# How to configure rabbitmq reply queues using spring-amqp?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

We are trying to make asynchronous call in RabbitMQ using Spring AMQP, could any one please tell me how to configure replyqueue, correlationId, (properties) using spring amqp?

```
    String corrId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();

 BasicProperties props = new BasicProperties
                                .Builder()
                                .correlationId(corrId)
                                .replyTo(replyQueueName)
                                .build();

 channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, message.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to use `RabbitTemplate`:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(requestQueueName, myObj, new MessagePostProcessor() {
   Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException {
      message.getMessageProperties().setReplyTo(replyQueueName);
      return message;  
   }
}, new CorrelationData(corrId));
```

HTH

Comment: The CorrelationData is used for publisher confirms not general correlation. Using this technique, you should set the correlation id in the `postProcessMessage`. Or, as I replied on the rabbit list, you can use one of the template's `...sendAndReceive...()` methods, and the template will take care of the correlation for you.

Comment: Thanks for response. Still am stuck while doing with spring amqp, below is the code at Producer end.


String corrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   String replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
   
   MessageProperties prop = new MessageProperties();
   prop.setCorrelationId(corrId.getBytes());
   prop.setReplyTo(replyQueueName);
   Message message = new Message(query.getBytes(), prop);
   Message msg = rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(message);


Could you please tell me how to get the channel here to get replyQueue and please share the consumer code as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To get a `channel` from Consumer, your `messageListener` should implement `ChannelAwareMessageListener`

Comment: Thanks for reply Bilen. The code I have shared above is at producer end. Do we really need ChannelAwareMessageListener implementation at producer end?

Comment: If you use `rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(message);` from producer there is no reason to have any `correlation` and `replyQueue`. Please, see Gary's answer

Comment: Ok. Then here we need to create the message object right? For this we need to create MessageProperties object right? It looks like this -

String data = "XYZ";
   Message message = new Message(data.getBytes(), new MessageProperties());
   Message receivedMsg = this.rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(message);

Is that fine? If yes, what about the consumer code?

Comment: You don't need to care about message creating: `RabbitTemplate` has another method - ``convertSendAndReceive`. There is nothing for consumer: you send data and receive result. That's all. If you need an asynchronous consumption, you should: 1. use `RabbitAdmin` to declare queue; 2. subscribe simple `MessageListener` to it; 3. place correlation data and replyQueue to the `MessageProperties` as you show above; 4. Use suggested method `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend`.

Comment: How do I access reply message in this case ?